# When I attach a controller to my fxml file, I get a constructLoadException

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using SceneBuilder to building a Java GUI Application. I tried to attach a Controller to my fxml file, so I could have actual functionality in my application. I should mention that it was running with no errors prior to this. When I attached the controller, I got this:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at t9.htmleditor.MainApp.showMainGUI(MainApp.java:54)
at t9.htmleditor.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:24)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1730989841.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/50177904.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.Button field t9.htmleditor.view.ToolContoller.PageTitle to javafx.scene.control.Button
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
```

I am nowhere near being able to interpret this and figure out what went wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's my controlller:

```
package t9.projectName.view;

import java.awt.Button;

import t9.hprojectName.MainApp;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class ToolContoller {

@FXML
private Group ToolGroup;

@FXML 
private AnchorPane TextTools;

@FXML
private Button Text;
@FXML
private Button TextHeader;
@FXML
private Button BackgroundColor;
@FXML
private Button Video;
@FXML
private Button PageTitle;
@FXML
private Button Templates;
@FXML
private Button Images;

// Reference to the main application.
private MainApp mainApp;

/**
 * The constructor.
 * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
 */
public ToolContoller() {
}


/**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 * 
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

}

/**
 * Called when the user clicks on the delete button.
 */
@FXML
private void handleTextButton() {
    TextTools.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on your imports. in your controller you have :

```
import java.awt.Button;
```

But you are in JavaFX so use :

```
import  javafx.scene.control.Button
```

This line on your stacktrace tell you what happened

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.Button field t9.htmleditor.view.ToolContoller.PageTitle to javafx.scene.control.Button